# Logging Application Block - Priority, Category values

Tags: logging, enterprise-library

I am looking for the best practices regarding the usage of the Enterprise Library's Logging Application Block and the Priority, Category and Severity values that one should use.

When it comes to Severity, the answer is quite simple: use one of the **`System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType`** enums.

But Priority is an int and Category is an array of strings. So I am not sure what is the best practice when it comes to these 2 values....

Here are two schemes that I have come up with when it comes to Category:

1. Use the class name for the category
2. Use a predefined category for different types of messages you except from your application (eg: Exception, Information, etc...).

**Advantage of 1:** It allows you to give great control over exactly which classes you want logging at any given point. (specify the class name and the severity to control what is logged and where its logged).

**Disadvantage of 1:** It can get unwieldy, as you may have 100s of categories and there is no easy way to setup configuration to capture all exceptions in the application.

**Advantage of 2:** Exact opposite of 1, so it makes it real easy to specify where you want all your exception messages to go and just as easily allows you to turn off logging of all unnecessary information.

**Disadvantage of 2:** Its not as configurable as (1).

Looking for other ideas when it comes to Priority and Category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But Priority is an int and Category is
>   an array of strings. So I am not sure
>   what is the best practice when it
>   comes to these 2 values....

In terms of priority I would recommend not using priority unless you have a specific requirement to log based on priority. If you don't explicitly need priority it causes more headaches than it's worth.

> Here are two schemes that I have come
>   up with when it comes to Category:
>
> 1. Use the class name for the category
> 2. Use a predefined category for different types of messages you except
>      from your application (eg: Exception,
>      Information, etc...).

In my experience the above two options are common choices.  **But why choose?** Since (as you mention) you can have more than one category there is no reason to choose one over the other.  If you wish, you can have multiple categories and enable only the ones you are interested in at the time.

For example, in addition to adding your class name (`MyCompany.BusinessLogic.Processor`) as a category you could also add the namespace or assembly name as a category (`MyCompany.BusinessLogic`).

Other categories that you could consider adding are categories by functional area or application layer. e.g. "DataAccess" or "UI".

I think if you use both of the approaches from your list that should cover most situations.  Enable "Exception" and if you need more granular logging you could turn Information on for specific classes or enable Information globally.